# How can i use the same object in different modules in Python3

Tags: python, class, object, module

If for example i have this class and i want to create object that will be used in different modules:

Module A

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
      self.a = #address to serial port

   def connect(self):
      self.a.connect() # assume that this connect to serial
   def write(self,toWrite):
       self.a.write(b"\x12")
```

Module C:

```
def func1():
    myObj = A()
    myObj.connect()
```

Module B:

```
def func2():
    A().write("a")
```

This is what i tried to do but this shows an error message, It seems like that in module B it uses a different object  than the one in C.

Is it possible to use the same object in different modules?If yes how can i import this object in different 2 modules?

Comment: Far better would be for `func1` to return `myObj` when called.  This should then be passed to `func2(myObj)` for manipulating.

Comment: This is impossible with my implementation because Module C and Module B are independent

Comment: Nonsense.  Module `X` can import `B` and `C` and then call `myObj = C.func1(); B.func2(myObj)`.  `B` and `C` don't need to know anything about each other.  In contrast, having some kind of shared global means `B` and `C` **do** need to know about each other so would hardly be "independent"

Comment: yeah but B and C are called from different independent modules